# How to change range of update for UISlider when VoiceOver is on?

Tags: ios, uikit, accessibility

When VoiceOver is on, select a `UISlider` and swipe up/down with 1 finger will increase/decrease the value by `10%`. I'm trying to make a bigger change (`25%`). How would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried accessibility increment and decrement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `UISlider` and implement `accessibilityIncrement` and `accessibilityDecrement` is the answer.